# What is wrong with these cronjobs?

Tags: linux, cron

My expectation is that the below instructions will make my script execute every 5 mins from 0930 to 1730 on weekdays.

```
30/5 9 * * 1,5 /home/main/.bin/somescript.sh
*/5 10-16 * * 1,5 /home/main/.bin/somescript.sh
0-30/5 17 * * 1,5 /home/main/.bin/somescript.sh
```

I installed `cronie` and tried to provide these instructions using `crontab -e`. I get the following output:

```
no crontab for main - using an empty one
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.6hY2xA":1: bad minute
Invalid crontab file, can't install.
```

I read a tip somewhere that the first and last line can not have cronjob instructions, I've attempted that, but get the same error.

What is my mistake?

Comment: It says line 1 has a bad minute specifier. What is 30/5 supposed to do?

Comment: @thatotherguy My understanding is that the first line is the correct syntax for 0930 - 1000 every 5 minutes on weekdays

Comment: I "tested" it on [this page](https://crontab.guru/). But obviously it's not correct then...

Comment: @heap1 That web page gave me a warning message: "Non standard! May not work with every cron." The color and background used for the error message make it difficult to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crontab(5) man page (`man 5 crontab`) says:

> Step  values  can  be  used in conjunction with ranges.  Following a
> range with "/" specifies skips of the number's value through
> the range.  For example, "0-23/2" can be used in the hours field to
> specify command execution every other hour (the alternative in the V7 standard
> is "0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22").  Steps are also permitted after
> an asterisk, so if you want to say "every two hours", just use
> "*/2".

So a step value like "/5" can be used with a range or an asterisk, but not with a single number.

Answer (score 0):

I had to edit the minute of the first line to `30-59/5`